Get the number of max values in a minute
I'd like to get the number of max values in a minute based on the data in my Sheets (this is my array of my Sheet above)
.
So I've created a function under apps script to obtain what I want (the desired result is 7 for this demonstration table).
function getNumberByMin(){
   var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var ss = ws.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   var tValues = ss.getRange("A2:B").getDisplayValues().filter(d=>d[0] != "");
   var minCheck = "", nbValuesByMin = 0, nbMaxValuesByMin = 0;

   for (let i = 0; i < tValues.length; i ++){
     var minSplit = tValues[i][0].toString().split(":")[1];
     // If "minCheck" is empty, "minCheck" is equal to "minSplit" and increment "nbValuesByMin"
     if (minCheck === ""){
       minCheck = minSplit;
       nbValuesByMin ++;
     }
     // Else if "minCheck" is equal to "minSplit", increment "nbValuesByMin"
     else if (minCheck === minSplit){
       nbValuesByMin ++;
       // If it's the last value of the array and "nbValuesByMin" is superior than "nbMaxValuesByMin", save "nbValuesByMin" in "nbMaxValuesByMin"
       if (i === tValues.length - 1 && nbValuesByMin > nbMaxValuesByMin){ nbMaxValuesByMin = nbValuesByMin; }
     }
     // Else if is not the same minute
     else{
       // if "nbMaxValuesByMin" is empty, save "nbValuesByMin" in "nbMaxValuesByMin", save the minute and initialize "nbValuesByMin" at 1
       if (nbMaxValuesByMin === 0){
         nbMaxValuesByMin = nbValuesByMin;
         minCheck = minSplit;
         nbValuesByMin = 1;
       }
       // else if "nbMaxValuesByMin" is not empty
       else{
         // if "nbValuesByMin" is superior than "nbMaxValuesByMin", save "nbValuesByMin" in "nbMaxValuesByMin", save the minute and initialize "nbValuesByMin" at 1
         if (nbValuesByMin > nbMaxValuesByMin){
           nbMaxValuesByMin = nbValuesByMin;
           minCheck = minSplit;
           nbValuesByMin = 1;
         }
         // else, save the minute and initialize "nbValuesByMin" at 1
         else{
           minCheck = minSplit;
           nbValuesByMin = 1;
         }
       }
     }
   }
   Logger.log(nbMaxValuesByMin)
 }

This function work perfectly but I've so many values and the runtime is too long. I would like optimize this.

It is unclear why you would need to do that in Apps Script when a plain vanilla formulas seems to suffice. Please explain.

I forgot to mention an important piece of data in my request: I need to determine the maximum number of values in one minute for different time ranges (see Sheets linked to the request). And I'll need to save the data every day in a database. That's why I've decided to wtite a script.

Please do not present new requirements after you have received an answer. Ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.

This is my implementation for the core section:
  let oMins = {};
  let iMax = [0,0]; //times, minute

      for (let i = 0; i < tValues.length; i++ ){
        const mins = tValues[i][0].toString().split(":")[1];
        if ( oMins[mins] == undefined ) oMins[mins] = 1;
        else oMins[mins]++;
      }
      for( blobs in oMins ) {
        if ( oMins[blobs] > iMax[0] ) iMax = [oMins[blobs], blobs];
      }

Once done, iMax will contain the count and the last minute with that count.
This implementation is shorter than the one in the provided sample, but not faster; it's just the test i done.
Gowl, note that the execution time (in your sample) is two orders of magnitude larger in the first three lines where tValues are populated than the core of the computation!

Thank's for your help jpp. It's work perfectly !

There is nothing obvious in the code that would explain why it runs slowly, but in in many cases, spreadsheet formulas can run faster than scripted solutions. Try this:
=query( 
  filter(minute(A2:A); istime_strict(A2:A)); 
  "select Col1, count(Col1) 
   group by Col1 
   order by count(Col1) desc"; 
  0 
)

The formula will get these results:




count




47
6


45
5


46
5


41
4


42
4


44
4


30
1



To get just the largest count, extract it from the second column of the second row, like this:
=choosecols( 
  chooserows(
    query( 
      filter(minute(A2:A); istime_strict(A2:A)); 
      "select Col1, count(Col1) 
       group by Col1 
       order by count(Col1) desc"; 
      0 
    ); 
    2 
  ); 
  2 
)

When a script runs slowly, the culprit is often found in the spreadsheet rather than in the code. See these spreadsheet optimization tips.
(new requirement introduced in a comment)

need to save the data every day in a database

Use a simple script that retrieves formula results from the spreadsheet and writes them in the database. Run the script on a time-driven trigger.
